# HackerRank challenge, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I am trying to do this challenge https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-if-else

I tried doing this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        x = 34;

        if ((x  % 2) != 0) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } else if (((x % 2 == 0) & ((x >= 2) & (5 >= x)))) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        } else if (((x % 2 == 0) & ((x >= 6) & (20 >= x)))) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } else if ((x % 2 == 0) & (x > 20)) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this in Intellij and it works fine, but here, I only get three test cases right. What am I doing wrong? I was overwhelmed by the scanner stuff, as I have not even covered that stuff yet in my own reading.

Comment: and what does "&" mean?

Comment: @TomekK in this context, it's the non-short circuiting AND operator.

Comment: Hint: Repeatedly checking `(x % 2 == 0)` is pointless. You already checked if that wasn't true, which means all other cases, it already is true.

Comment: Note: your IDE will almost never matter in a StackOverflow question, except if your question is about your IDE itself. Don't include it in your the tags of the question

Comment: Yep, but it's still worth mentionning it. That was most likely not the original intent of the OP

Comment: I just tested your solution and it passes all the tests. Maybe you don't understand how to run the tests.

Answer (score 2):

> HackerRank challenge, what am I doing wrong?

You are not reading the number from Standard Input, so the tests are all checking the output for the number 34.

Replace

```
int x;
x = 34;
```

With this (which is what the test started with)

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int x=sc.nextInt();
```

Do that, your tests pass fine.

---

Alternate solution

```
boolean even = x % 2 == 0;
boolean weird = !even || (even && (6 <= x && x <= 20));
System.out.println(weird ? "Weird" : "Not Weird");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using && as a conditional operator. Also you don't need to have the if statement check if it is even, as the first if statement provided in their code already checks if it's odd. If it isn't (only other option is even) it goes to the else statement. Elegant solution listed below.

The scanner simply is just what is passed in, don't worry about it, just use the value n, they will pass the value into the code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();            
        String ans="";
        if(n%2==1){ // only if it's odd
          ans = "Weird";
        }
        // only enters else if the value is even
        else{
            if (n >= 6 && n <= 20) { // between 6 and 20
                ans = "Weird";
            } else { // only other option is greater than 20 
                     // or below 6 which includes 2 through 5
                ans = "Not Weird";
            }

        }
        System.out.println(ans);

    }
```

EDIT: Saw that his ranges are in a non-traditional order, so it is fine. Not sure what was wrong prior.

Comment: "Elegant solution listed below" If you read the constraints in the problem, you can simplify it further. Also, `else if` instead of `else { if`.

Comment: Oops sorry glanced for about a minute haha, my bad, the else is provided, wanted OP to just fill in where they have // put code here, didnt want to modify the given part.

Comment: Are you sure the ranges are wrong? Running the code above passes all the test cases

Comment: Just saw that it was in a non-conventional order, it is fine, yeah it works. Not sure what happened. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is better^^

I cannot comment (rep too low), but you don't need to check if it is even each time after the first check. You can assume that if it is not odd, then it is even.

An easier/simpler way of writing your code is:

```
String answer = "";
    if ((x  % 2) != 0) {//if odd
        answer = "Weird";
    } 
    else { //if even
         if ((x > 1) && (x < 6)) {
            answer = "Not Weird";
    } 
         else if ((x > 5) && (x < 21)) {
            answer = "Weird";
    }    
         else if (x > 20) {
            answer = "Not Weird";
    }
System.out.println(answer);
```

By not using "equal to" operators and changing your order in the "less than" side you could solve your problem.

Comment: "The above answer is better^^" There are 3 answers showing above yours on my screen. Please [edit] your answer to add a link to the specific answer you are referring to (use the "share" link under that answer to get the URL).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, has passed HackerRank tests, inside their else:

```
if ((n % 2 == 0) & ((n >= 2) & (5 >= n))) 
    System.out.println("Not Weird");
if ((n % 2 == 0) & ((n >= 6) & (20 >= n))) 
    System.out.println("Weird");
if ((n % 2 == 0) & (n > 20)) 
    System.out.println("Not Weird");
```

Just changed to "else if" to "if".